# Are dimen values cached?

Tags: android

Is there any performance gain over doing the following:

```
final int pixels = getResources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pixels);
for (CustomView view: views) {
    view.setPixelValue(pixels);
}
```

vs.

```
for (CustomView view: views) {
    view.setPixelValue(getResources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.pixels));
}
```

Or are dimens values cached / the bytecode optimised / some other optimisation that makes this redundant?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/167938/does-it-make-a-difference-if-i-declare-variables-inside-or-outside-a-loop-in-jav

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Resources.getDimentionPixelSize()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/res/Resources.java#Resources.getDimensionPixelSize(int)) and deeper till [AssetManager.loadResourceValue()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/res/AssetManager.java#AssetManager.loadResourceValue%28int%2Cshort%2Candroid.util.TypedValue%2Cboolean%29) which is native it's impossible to say. However, from `Resources.getDimentionPixelSize()` source it's possible to say the following:

```
public int getDimensionPixelSize(int id) throws NotFoundException {
    synchronized (mAccessLock) {
        TypedValue value = mTmpValue;
        if (value == null) {
            mTmpValue = value = new TypedValue();
        }
        getValue(id, value, true);
        if (value.type == TypedValue.TYPE_DIMENSION) {
            return TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
                    value.data, mMetrics);
        }
        throw new NotFoundException(
                "Resource ID #0x" + Integer.toHexString(id) + " type #0x"
                + Integer.toHexString(value.type) + " is not valid");
    }
}
```

- It will lock resources by `synchronized (mAccessLock)`  (read, if some other thread of you will try to access resources same moment - on of them will wait);
- It will call some float math inside `TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize()`;
- It will probably create `TypedValue` object;
- It will do at least 5 method calls;

So, maybe it's cached somewhere in native, but even so, call will be definitely not free for you.
Here's some measurements I've done for this question (with only single thread accessing resources):

```
    int pixels = 0;
    Resources res = getResources();
    long ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        pixels = res.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.my_dimen);
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Time " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - ms));
```

On S6 with Android Lollipop it gives about *816 ms*, or *8160 nano-sec / call*.

Finally, in your case (I believe you have maximum 10-20 iterations) it really doesn't matter in terms of performance. In more iterations and / or some concurrency in access to resources in might be significant.

Personally I would suggest to do it outside for better style and small but still speed improvement.